# JavaScript игра в пары, добавление кнопки после завершения игры и ее перезапуск

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как обновить и запустиь корректно функцию гейм старт при условии если все пары открыты и нажата кнопка?
В моем примере кода, при нажатии кнопки все дублируется как и дом дерево так и элементы:

```js
(function () {




  let cardsCount = 2;
  // let cardsCount = prompt("Введите количество пар", 2);
  const cardsNumberArray = []
  // const game = document.getElementById("game");
  let firstCard = null;
  let seconCard = null;



  //создание массива
  function createNumbersArray(count) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
      cardsNumberArray.push(i, i);
    }
  }




  function shuffle(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
      let temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[randomIndex];
      arr[randomIndex] = temp;
    }
    return arr;
  }
 

  function addTitle() {
    const title = document.createElement("h1");
    title.classList.add("mb-5");
    title.style.textAlign = "center";
    title.textContent = "Игра в пары";
    return title;
  }


  function startGame(container, count) {
    createNumbersArray(count);
    shuffle(cardsNumberArray);

    const body = document.getElementById("title");
    const title = addTitle();
    body.append(title);


    for (const cardNumber of cardsNumberArray) {
      const card = document.createElement("div");
      card.textContent = cardNumber;
      card.classList.add("card");
      container.append(card);
      card.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (card.classList.contains("open") || card.classList.contains("success")) {
          return
        }

        if (firstCard !== null && seconCard !== null) {
          firstCard.classList.remove("open");
          seconCard.classList.remove("open");
          firstCard = null;
          seconCard = null;
        }
        // console.log(card);
        card.classList.add("open");
        if (firstCard === null) {
          firstCard = card;
        } else {
          seconCard = card;
        }
        if (firstCard !== null && seconCard !== null) {
          let firstCardNumber = firstCard.textContent
          let secondCardNumber = seconCard.textContent
          if (firstCardNumber === secondCardNumber) {
            firstCard.classList.add("success");
            seconCard.classList.add("success");
          }

        }

        if (cardsNumberArray.length === document.querySelectorAll(".success").length) {
          // setTimeout(function () {
          //   alert("Игра завершена, вы выйграли!")
          // }, 400);
          const gameButton = document.querySelector(".game-button");
          const button = document.createElement("button");
          button.textContent = "Сыграть еще раз";
          gameButton.append(button);


          button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            // document.querySelectorAll('.card').remove(card);
            let cardsNumberArray = [];
            // while (document.body.firstChild) {
            //   document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
            // }
            startGame(document.getElementById('game'), 2);
            console.log(cardsNumberArray);
          });

        }
      });
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    startGame(document.getElementById('game'), cardsCount);
  });

})();
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


body {
  min-width: 320px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
}

/* glob */
.list-reset {
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.btn-reset {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
/* Начало */
.game {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 40px 15px;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(226, 187, 137);
  font-size: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: rgb(241, 213, 176);
}

.card:active {
  background-color: rgb(204, 159, 100);
}

.open {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2b18d6;
  transition: background-color .1s;
  cursor: default;
}

.open:hover {
  background-color: #2b18d6;
}

.open:active {
  background-color: #2b18d6;
}

.success {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #25d618;
  transition: background-color .1s;
  cursor: default;
}

.success:hover {
  background-color: #25d618;
}

.success:active {
  background-color: #25d618;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

  <title>Игра в пары</title>

  <script defer src="main.js"></script>
  <script>
    // let cardsCount = Number(prompt("Введите количество пар", 8));
    // const cardsCount = 2;
    // document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    //   startGame(document.getElementById('game'), cardsCount);
    // });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="title"></div>
  <div id="game" class="container game"></div>
  <div class="game-button"></div>
</body>

</html>
```